# Shadow status is out of sync in aws iot how to resolve

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I am working on aws iot and able to get the shadow state updated by the terminal via shell script .But i am able to get 
root@raspberrypi:~# ./aws_subscribe.py
Connected with result code 0
and also in aws iot home i am getting out of sync error
The is attached below. 
[I followed the following link](https://www.awsomeblog.com/amazon-web-services-iot/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [on\_message is not working in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984677/on-message-is-not-working-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

This is as far as I can get. This is me running on a raspberry pi so I need the certs. Im not sure if you need the certs on lambda. The shadow state is returned in the custom callback.  This is they way that have decided to do it.  I still cant figure out how to get the shadow state outside the callback so you can actually do something useful with it other than print.

```
   from AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib import AWSIoTMQTTShadowClient
   import logging
   import json 


def get(payload, responseStatus, token):
    dict = json.loads(payload)
    print(str(dict["state"]["desired"]["State"])) #make sure this matches your shadow names



# Read in command-line parameters
useWebsocket = False
host = "XXXXXYourINFO HEREXXXXXX.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
rootCAPath = "XXXXXYourINFO HEREXXXXXX"
certificatePath = "XXXXXYourINFO HEREXXXXXX"
privateKeyPath = "XXXXXYourINFO HEREXXXXXX"


# Configure logging
logger = logging.getLogger("AWSIoTPythonSDK.core")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
streamHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(streamHandler)

# Init AWSIoTMQTTShadowClient

myAWSIoTMQTTShadowClient = AWSIoTMQTTShadowClient("basicShadowUpdater")
myAWSIoTMQTTShadowClient.configureEndpoint(host, 8883)
myAWSIoTMQTTShadowClient.configureCredentials(rootCAPath, privateKeyPath, certificatePath)

# AWSIoTMQTTShadowClient configuration
myAWSIoTMQTTShadowClient.configureAutoReconnectBackoffTime(1, 32, 20)
myAWSIoTMQTTShadowClient.configureConnectDisconnectTimeout(10)  # 10 sec
myAWSIoTMQTTShadowClient.configureMQTTOperationTimeout(5)  # 5 sec

# Connect to AWS IoT
myAWSIoTMQTTShadowClient.connect()

# Create a deviceShadow with persistent subscription
Bot = myAWSIoTMQTTShadowClient.createShadowHandlerWithName("GarageRBP", True)

#get the shadow here and the state is included in the custom callback
Bot.shadowGet(get, 5)
```