# on_message is not working in python

Tags: aws-iot

I am working on aws iot and able to get the shadow state updated by the terminal via shell script .But i am able to get root@raspberrypi:~# ./aws_subscribe.py Connected with result code 0 and also in aws iot home i am getting out of sync error  [image: The is attached below]
and  [i am following this blog](https://www.awsomeblog.com/amazon-web-services-iot/#comment-1735)

Answer (score 0):

The 'Shadow status' field on the AWS console merely shows if the 'reported' and 'desired' states are the same, it has no functional impact.

This is an example that would show the status as out of sync:

```
{
  "reported": {
    "locked": true
  },
  "desired": {
    "locked": false
  }
}
```

Where as this example would show them as in sync.

```
{
  "reported": {
    "locked": true
  },
  "desired": {
    "locked": true
  }
}
```

That's really all there is to it. You can completely remove the 'desired' state by sending the following JSON, if you do this it will always show as in sync.

```
{
  "desired": null
}
```